# why do we need assertion, without assertion also directly we can write script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

1.Without assertion also directly we can write script and
 when it will fail we                                                             can find from output.

2.Suppose file did not upload then from output we can find the error,
  why do we need assertion ,as its not solving problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking assertions are fatal errors that catch major errors like incorrect data types being returned, however different languages implement them in a different way. They are the most basic and least friendly of all error handling methods.

Assertions are used as markers for debugging or test builds of program, typically when you build compiled code for production all assertions are stripped from the code and replaced with handlers.

In scripted test code assertions are used to mark what are the significant comparisons used for the test. E.g checking that a specific return code matches the one you expect. Scripted test code typically runs within an exception handler that catches assertions which allows it to catch the state and present more information about data that caused it to fail.

In compiled code assertions can be used like breakpoints if you run it via a debugger, this allows for a similar ability to examine the program state although in practice this is much harder.

Answer (score 0):

Properly written assertions tell you immediately when something isn't working. If you are doing some end to end test and your test has no assertions, it may be a few pages after the problem when your script fails. Then you have to backtrack and find where the issue actually occurred. If you write assertions as you go, you can validate things are working properly as each action is performed so that you know exactly when something didn't go as expected. It makes finding and isolating the issue faster.